# what are the rewards for the righteous in Olam Haba?

Tags: reward-punishment, olam-haba-world-to-come, tzaddikim, afterlife

I am looking for some sources from chazal on what rewards await the righteous in olam haba (the afterlife). preferably some kind of comprehensive treatise rather than bits and pieces.